# Plugging an old MBP into a newer hub (TB2>TB4/USB-C)

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, displayport

I have a mid-2014 MacBook Pro, which has 2x Thuderbolt 2, an HDMI and 2x (degraded) USB 3 ports.

I also have a new Kensington Thunderbolt 4 hub, with two monitors connected to it (TB4>DisplayPort). This is usually plugged in to my work computer.

Does a solution exist to plug my MBP into the hub to drive those two monitors (e.g., a TB2>TB4 cable)? I haven't been able to find one, so I'm not holding out much hope. Maybe my only option would be to bypass the hub and plug directly into the monitors with both a TB2>DisplayPort and an HDMI cable.